# Using TSQL to generate XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I am trying to generate some XML using TSQL and having some trouble, I was able to get to traverse 2 levels but getting stuck at 3.  How it should work in the example I have posted you have to Purchase Orders, the first purchase order only has one part with one release for that part.  The second Purchase order as 2 parts each part with its own release.  At the end I should have 2 XML documents that traverse 3 levels, release/part/purchase order.  I think I am getting confused when linking to the next stage up as well as the group by.The example only shows 2 parts but there can be many parts to one purchase order but only ever one release per part, any help would be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @sdv AS TABLE    
(
PID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
PurchaseOrder varchar(20),
PartNo int,
Release int
)


INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC123', 111, 1)
INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC333', 222, 1)
INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC333', 333, 1)


select 
    PurchaseOrder,
(
select
    PartNo,
(
select
    Release
from
@sdv a3
where 
a3.Release = a2.Release and
a3.PartNo = a2.PartNo and 
a3.PurchaseOrder = a1.PurchaseOrder
for xml path('Release'), type
) 
from 
@sdv a2
where 
a2.PartNo = a1.PartNo
group by a2.PartNo
for xml path('part'), type
) from @sdv a1
group by PurchaseOrder
for xml path('Purchase')
```

Comment: Can you write the XML you want to get from current data set so I can understand it better?

Comment: Could you please include a sample output in XML format.  I have several working options but want to make sure I have the right one for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to shoot you an answer so you can play around with it.  I am around for a little bit longer today, but will check back tomorrow.

For this example I just used attributes as I can read it a bit easier.  I did my grouping using a CTE and assumed the relationship was 1 to many between a part and a release.  (could be wrong there, but need info from you).  Was also a bit hazy about the levels needing to go a third deep.  If we are talking about iterations of parts (versions) then you could simple add a @Release to the second level.  Note: If you don't want attributes just remove the @before each of the tags.

**I would highly recommend being very diligent about your code format whenever doing hierarchical xml work.  Its easy to get lost.**

**CODE**

```
DECLARE @sdv AS TABLE    
(
PID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
PurchaseOrder varchar(20),
PartNo int,
Release int
)


INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC123', 111, 1)
INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC333', 222, 1)
INSERT INTO @sdv values ('PURC333', 333, 1)

;WITH PO AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT PurchaseOrder
    FROM    @sdv
)
SELECT  L1.PurchaseOrder AS "@PurchseOrder",
        (   SELECT  PartNo AS "@PartNo",
                    (   SELECT  DISTINCT L3.Release AS "@Release"
                        FROM    @sdv AS L3
                        WHERE   L2.PartNo = L3.PartNo
                        ORDER   BY L3.Release ASC
                        FOR     XML PATH('RELEASE'),TYPE
                    )
            FROM    @sdv AS L2
            WHERE   L2.PurchaseOrder = L1.PurchaseOrder
            FOR XML PATH('PART'), TYPE
        )       
FROM    PO AS L1
FOR     XML PATH('PurchaseOrder'), ROOT('PurchaseOrders')
```

**XML OUTPUT**

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchseOrder="PURC123">
    <PART PartNo="111">
      <RELEASE Release="1" />
    </PART>
  </PurchaseOrder>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchseOrder="PURC333">
    <PART PartNo="222">
      <RELEASE Release="1" />
    </PART>
    <PART PartNo="333">
      <RELEASE Release="1" />
    </PART>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</PurchaseOrders>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the quick response, this is almost exactly what I wanted, my apologies to yourself and the other people that replied I should of posted some example XML.  Though this is the format that I wanted, I would like to break each Purchase Order Out individually as I need to created separate files for each purchase order to ftp to another company.  I have tried adding in a Group By but still not getting the desired result, can I ask for your further assistance please!

Comment: Sorry I missed answering your question, if I understood your question correctly, there will only ever be 1 release per part but many parts to one purchase order, hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Matt, After some further amendments to your original script I am almost there, I now have it by Purchase Order, a Column that lists the purchase and then the column with the XML though unfortunately it has gone back to looking like when you use AUTO instead of PATH so the format isn't quite as it was, can you help

Comment: Good morning.  I'll be in the office here another couple hours and glad to help.  Could you post sample xml in the meantime.  That would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have managed to do what I was after but only after inserting the results back in to a table with a column data type of xml which I am sure is not the best way, is there a way I can repost my amended code on here?? and you can see the results as this will show you what I am after even if I am not doing it in the best way, thanks again

Comment: Yes just edit your question. Wrap any code xml or tsql in code tags. When you're satisfied don't forget to accept an answer.